# In C# how to show a GUI from another GUI, based on the event from a class in another thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, user-interface, dialog

I am working on a DirectX based simulator.
On which I have to check for a device whether device has been plugged-in or removed from the PC.

I've managed to make classes for device arrival and removal on another thread, which raises an event from the thread itself *on device arrival or removal*.
The corresponding event method is being called in the main form and there:

Assume `Form1` is main window and `Form2` is the secondary.

```
Form2 form2Instance = new Form2();
```

I want to show another Form (`Form2`) keeping main Window (`Form1`) in behind (same as it behaves as `form2Instance.ShowDialog();` in general cases.)
After a few tries I have done it by

`Applicatin.Run(new Form2());`, but the Form2 doesn't behave as'`form2Instance.ShowDialog();` in any way.

Just giving the code if it can help in answering:

```
iARMdetectionThreadClass detection;
InProgram_iARMdetection iARMStatusGUI;

 private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         iARMStatusGUI = new InProgram_iARMdetection();
         detection = new iARMdetectionThreadClass();
         detection.IniARM_device_Arrive += new iARMdetectionThreadClass.iARM_device_ArrivedEventHandler(detection_IniARM_device_Arrive);
         detection.IniARM_device_Remove += new iARMdetectionThreadClass.iARM_device_RemovedEventHandler(detection_IniARM_device_Remove);
         detection.startThread();
        }


 void detection_IniARM_device_Remove(iARM_deviceInfo senderInfo)
        {

            detection.StopCheckBeingRemoved();
            MethodInvoker act = delegate
            {
                this.label_iARMStatus.Text = detection.iARM_deviceInf.iARMStatus;
            };
            this.label_iARMStatus.BeginInvoke(act);

            Application.Run(new InProgram_iARMdetection()); //Blocking code

            detection.StartCheckBeingRemoved();

        }

 void detection_IniARM_device_Arrive(iARM_deviceInfo senderInfo)
        {
            MethodInvoker act = delegate
            {
                this.label_iARMStatus.Text = detection.iARM_deviceInf.iARMStatus;
            };
            this.label_iARMStatus.BeginInvoke(act);
            //detection.StopCheckArriving();
            //detection.StartCheckArriving();
        }
```

I need the code to be *Blocking Code*. In here:

```
Application.Run(new InProgram_iARMdetection()); //Blocking code
```

Comment: The appeared dialog has to diapear by itself, if device is again plugged-in to the PC. Which performs well, but behind the main window.

Comment: Obviously, if you want form2 to be displayed as dialog you must use the ShowDialog() method. Why are you using Application.Run instead of ShowDialog() inside the event?

Comment: @Aseem Gautam: Bcos when I use form2Instance.ShowDialog(), first time it shows, after that it disappears also, but doesnt work well on next remove event. Don't know why. so Application.Run(new Form2());

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [`mainform.AddOwnedForm(form2)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.addownedform.aspx) will do what you want. It will make `form2` display in front of `mainform` and when either one is minimized, the other is also.

Comment: Yes, or just `form2.Show(this)`

Comment: Not working as needed. :( If you need any other reference plz mention.

Comment: When I try AddOwnedForm() then when I call .show() it shows:

System.InvalidOperationException: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'OnProgram_iARMdetection' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.UpdateHandleWithOwner()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.set_Owner(Form value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.AddOwnedForm(Form ownedForm)


OnProgram_iARMdetection has been instantiated in the main form itself and both addOwnedForm() and Show() fns are being called from main form itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the remove event on form2 rather than form1 and use the ShowDialog() method.

So when on form1 the arrival event will fire it will open up form2 like a dialog. Now when the device will be unplugged, on form2 removal event will fire where you can close the form.